# Looping issue in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

This is a very basic problem I am dealing with.

I have simulated a dataset with 6 variables and I want to measure dynamic extremen shortfall for each of the vectors.

I am trying to loop the following code in a way, that the final variable ES will present a matrix that will have T rows and 6 colums going through all data points in the simulated rectengular matrix.

```
clc
clear
%% Simulate data set
mu = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
A = rand(6);
Sigma= A * A';

%% Simulation of variables
rng('default')  % For reproducibility
Data = mvnrnd(mu,Sigma,1000);
r=Data(:,1);
```

I want to use r = Data in that the estimation runs on all columns instead of on each column and the final ESmatrix plots all columns in one plot.

```
 T= length(r);
    conditionalvariance=[];
    p= [0.025];
    VarMdl = garch(1,1)
    Mdl = arima('ARLags',1,'Variance',VarMdl);
    EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,r);
    [res,v,logL] = infer(EstMdl,r);
    conditionalvariance=[conditionalvariance,v];
    Sigma=conditionalvariance;
    ESdynamic=[];
    VaRdynamic=[];
    bpoe=[];
    for J= 1:T
    [Var_Normal, ES_Normal]=hNormalVaRES(Sigma(J),p);
    VaR=Var_Normal;
    ES=ES_Normal;
    disp(J)
    disp('');
    ESdynamic=[ESdynamic,ES];
    VaRdynamic=[]
    end
    ES=ESdynamic;
    Local Functions:
    function [VaR,ES] = hNormalVaRES(Sigma,p)
        % Compute VaR and ES for normal distribution
        % See [4] for technical details
        
        VaR = -norminv(p);
        ES = -Sigma*quad(@(q)q.*normpdf(q),-6,-VaR)/p;
    
    end
```

When I plot(ES), i want to have a plot of 6 variables.

Please kindly help me out with this looping issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the plot is expected to look like this but using an additional outer for-loop to index through the values of `p` and run the function multiple times can be used to achieve this result. To plot the same axes the `hold on` property was introduced after the first `plot()` call. Also not sure if `p = [0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.001]` is the correct set since you mentioned it was for six different `p` values. In the question it had `0.1` as `0,1`.

[image: 6 Combined Plots]

```
clc
clear
% Simulate data set
mu = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
A = rand(6);
Sigma= A * A';

% Simulation of variables
rng('default')  % For reproducibility
Data = mvnrnd(mu,Sigma,1000);
r=Data(:,1);
T= length(r);
conditionalvariance=[];
p = [0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.001];


VarMdl = garch(1,1)
Mdl = arima('ARLags',1,'Variance',VarMdl);
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,r);
[res,v,logL] = infer(EstMdl,r);
conditionalvariance=[conditionalvariance,v];
Sigma=conditionalvariance;
ESdynamic=[];
VaRdynamic=[];
bpoe=[];

for P_Index = 1: +1: length(p) 
P_Value = p(P_Index);
for J= 1:T
[Var_Normal, ES_Normal]=hNormalVaRES(Sigma(J),P_Value);
VaR = Var_Normal;
ES = ES_Normal;
disp(J)
disp('');
ESdynamic = [ESdynamic,ES];
VaRdynamic = []
end
ES_Matrix(:,P_Index) = ESdynamic';
plot(ES_Matrix(:,P_Index));
hold on

ESdynamic = [];
end 
hold off

function [VaR,ES] = hNormalVaRES(Sigma,p)
    % Compute VaR and ES for normal distribution
    % See [4] for technical details
    
    VaR = -norminv(p);
    ES = -Sigma*quad(@(q)q.*normpdf(q),-6,-VaR)/p;

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: MichaelTr7, thank you so much m y friend. While this is one way of looking into things, what I wanted is to get ESdynamic as a matrix , where the columns are not p values, but considering each columns as a different variable. Let us consider p=0.05 only. But how can i run a loop to make a matrix of ESdynamic. The ES analysis is conducted on each column. I want them to work on all columns through a loop. So, instead of using r=Data(:,1);...I want the loop to go through r = Data(:, 1:end) with only p=0.05. How to edit the code for that mate?

Comment: I've got no clue what you exactly want. A more streamlined example of what you're trying to achieve might help me figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi MichaelTr7, thank you mate. I have updated the question and the code for your consideration. I want ES to be estimated for each columns in a loop as we have a matrix as an input.

Comment: Hi MichaelTr7, I have updated this question in Create a matrix by looping the estimation in columns....if you can comment there and help would really be great

Comment: thank you so much. This solved my problem.

Comment: @Mihan No problem, happy it helped!